# In R how do you take a sample of size n without replacement where length of vector sampling from is <= n

Tags: r, sampling

When I run the following I get an error:

```
sample(c(1,4),5,replace=FALSE)
```

This is the error:

```
  Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'
```

Is there a way to sample without replacement where it just automatically stops sampling once there is nothing left to sample? The result in this case I would like to be 1,4 or 4,1.

Comment: You can't. It's a logical impossibility.

Comment: But you *could* write a wrapper function that compares the size of the sample you request with the length of your population and then adjusts the second argument to `sample` accordingly.

Comment: Just use `sample(c(1,4),length(c(1,4)),replace=FALSE)`

Comment: Something like `sample(options, min(length(options), 5), replace=FALSE)` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an `if else` statement.

```
size_n <- 5
vec <- c(1, 4)

if (length(vec) < size_n) {
  sample(vec, length(vec), replace = F)
} else {
    sample(vec, size_n, replace = F)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If we generalize the question in a way to "take sample size up to n" without replacement, we can do:

```r
population <- c(1, 4)
samplesize_max <- 5

sample(population, min(length(population), samplesize_max), replace = FALSE)
```